# Aurelia: Table + CSS

Tags: html, css, aurelia

this issue happens on google chrome and ie, firefox is working fine.

after scrolling the table, the image preview is running off its original position.

without scrolling all rows are working.

image preview visible when hover table row.

```
export class App {
    data: Array<number> = [];

    constructor() {
        for (let i=0; i<100; i++) {
           this.data.push(i);
        }
    }
}


<div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
</div>
<div style="overflow-y: auto; height: 200px;">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr repeat.for="d of data">
                <td>
                    <div class="preview">${d}
                        <span><img src="http://science-all.com/images/wallpapers/image/image-6.jpg" style="height: 200px;"/></span>
                    </div>
               </td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

here is the example [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Kpxo6E0SVjnRU8rmqMBV?p=info)

any css fix or work around?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow-y: auto; height: 200px;">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr repeat.for="d of data">
          <td>
            <div class="preview"><div>${d}</div>
              <div id="imgdiv"><img src="http://science-all.com/images/wallpapers/image/image-6.jpg" style="height: 200px;"/></div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>
```

and CSS

/* Styles go here */

```
.preview #imgdiv{
  display: none;
  float: left;
  position:absolute;

}
.preview
{
  position:relative;
}

.preview:hover #imgdiv{
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 5px;
   margin-left:20px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, is it possible to make the preview looks like outside the table? i tried your codes, each scrolling, the preview for last few rows are difficult to see it because of table's height blocking.

Comment: no its working fine even if u hover the last row the height auto adjust there is no problem in that